# LetsEncrypt: Automatic certificate renewals without web server and DNS/configuration changes

Tags: dns, certificate, letsencrypt

Is there ANY way to automatically renew LetsEncrypt certificates without

1. Having an A record to that domain
2. Updating the DNS zone at each renew

Example: I would like to use it for my XMPP server which uses SRV records. I do **not** want to add an A record.

I could manually add a TXT record. However, it seems this must be done at each renewal and hence, it is not practical. I do NOT want to change a TXT record at each renewal.

I could use `nsupdate` in a script but I do **not** want to set up dynamic DNS just for that.

Methods I could think of:

1. Put a public key as TXT record in DNS (one time!). Each renewal, a challenge is signed with the corresponding private key. By far the most elegant
2. A special SRV record which points to a service where a temporary TCP server is opened to service that request
3. An email with a challenge is sent to an address in whois of the parent domain which is automatically replied to using an SMTP server

Answer (score 0):

There are [several different challenge methods](https://ietf-wg-acme.github.io/acme/draft-ietf-acme-acme.html#rfc.section.8) as part of the [ACME spec](https://ietf-wg-acme.github.io/acme/draft-ietf-acme-acme.html).  These are the only ways you can verify your domain, so you will have to choose one of the specified challenge methods.  Based on your description the DNS challenge (setting a TXT record) sounds like the easiest method to use without setting up/exposing a webserver, but you will have to decided which is best for your situation.